# Cannot delete or update a parent row: Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-migrations

I want to delete a record in `category` table wherein it will also delete the `subcategory` record which has a the `foreign key` of `category`. How can I do this?

Also, an explanation would help as why it has happened. Thank you!

**Controller**

```
public function destroy(Category $category)
{
    // return $category;
    Category::where('id', $category->id)->delete();
    Subcategory::where('category_id', $category->id)->delete();
    return back();
}
```

**Category migration**

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Sub-category mgiration**

```
Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('subcatname');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

this is simple because of the default `delete: Restrict option` in foreign key.
1.Add on delete cascade option to  foreign key. This option will automatically remove any associated records from the subcategoires table when you delete the category record.
The modified fk statement looks like as follows:

```
 ADD CONSTRAINT `category_subcategory_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

or you can go through

Laravel also provides support for creating foreign key constraints, which are used to force referential integrity at the database level. For example, let's define a user_id column on the posts table that references the id column on a users table:

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

});

You may also specify the desired action for the "on delete" and "on update" properties of the constraint:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
  ->references('id')->on('users')
  ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `onDelete` method. Just from [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

```
$table->foreign('category_id')
      ->references('id')->on('categories')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```